# Save GNU Screen session layout after reboot

Tags: gnu-screen, reboot, session

I would like to retain/restore the following properties of a GNU Screen after reboot:

- Name and number of screen sessions
- Name and number of windows inside every screen
- Screen splitting (i.e., position + size of screens)
- Current working directories of the shells
- (Environment variables)

It explicitly does not have to include running processes because I already know and understand that's not possible.

Is it possible to save those properties of a session, so I can restore it easily after reboot?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I do know that it [is possible](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) to do what you want using [``tmux``](http://tmux.github.io) instead of ``screen``, which might or might not be an option in your situation.

Comment: Ok, thank you @MarkPerryman for that suggestion. If that's really not possible, I should evaluate whether it's helpful to switch to tmux.